# Geo data to Database for Reporting

Tags: mysql, database, google-maps, maps, distance

We need geodata for our reports and also for other apps. Primarily we will need distances and coordinates. We already thought about Google Maps API but the problem here is that you are not allowed to store the data into your own database. But then it comes to reporting it will be necessary to store the results, so we don't have to load the data from the API every time (costs & time). Are there services that allow to store data and use it for this purpose or maybe a work around to use the Google API for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use leaflets library to load maps and your own geo-data. 
Also there are tools to manage information stored in MySQL database to be displayed on a map using leaflet library similar to google maps.
Just google leaflet php MySQL map
Or build your own php or Javascript code to generate a geojson from MySQL data. Then display geojson data on leaflet map.
Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Seems interesting. Another way we cam up with is Open Street Data. It provides Geo coordinates and also route/road data (Distances).Also it's possible to store it in our own DB.